# Is it possible to change the order by "DESC/ASC" in a case statment - MySql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a select statement with a order by command. Now the order by command has a case statment based on the status of the record it sort by a different column. However, I need to also the order by DESC if the status = 1 else order by ASC.

How can I do this?

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT ph.phone_call_id AS id, ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
       ph.trigger_on AS triggerOn,
       ph.isAppointment,
       IFNULL(ph.last_attempt_on, "") last_attempt_on,
       ind.name AS industry,
       ac.account_id,
       ac.account_name AS accountName
       FROM phone_calls AS ph
       INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
       INNER JOIN industries AS ind ON ind.industry_id = ac.industry_id
       INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ph.call_code_id = cc.call_code_id
       WHERE ac.status = 1 
       AND ph.status = '.$call_status.' 
       AND ph.owner_id = '. USER_ID .' 
       AND ac.do_not_call = 0 
       ORDER BY CASE WHEN ph.status = 1 THEN ph.trigger_on ELSE ph.last_attempt_on END
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ph.status = 1 THEN ph.trigger_on  end) DESC,
         (case when ph.status <> 1 then ph.last_attempt_on END) ASC
```

Comment: Can you have the same field but with ASC and DESC depending on another field?